# How to change color of word from whole string of button in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi i want to change the color of word from whole string that is text of button tkinter.

**code**

```
def get_alarm():            
    al_off = "Alarm is set to OFF \n Set Alarm to ON"            
    self.btn_value.set(al_off)

get_alarm()

self.alarm = PhotoImage(file='images/bell2.png')
self.alarm_btn = Button(self.frame2, text="", image=self.alarm, compound=TOP,
                               background='pink', activebackground='#FF7F50', foreground='green',
                               font=('times new roman', 16), textvariable=self.btn_value)
```

i want to change the color of only "ON" to green. how to do this

Comment: You can draw a image of text for this. I think there is no built in way to achive this with tkinter.

Comment: If i save ON IN another variable and change color and then format into the variable. Can it be done

Comment: No. It could be done if you would write your own Button with a Canvas and give that button the abuilty for multicolored foreground. Quickest way to go is to use PIL, since you already use it and draw a picture of your text.